# Unable to access a Grafana dashboard running on an AWS EC2 through internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tcp, grafana

I have installed and initiated Grafana on a AWS EC2 Windows server. I can access the dashboard when logged into the EC2, by typing in the 'private IP address':3000. The dashboard loads up and I can do what I want. Interestingly, I cannot access the dashboard if i try the 'public IP address':3000.

However, i want to access the dashboard from the internet - so not when logged into the EC2. So, to begin with, i created new security rules, by creating new inbound and outbound TCP rules for port 3000, see below.

[image]

Now, when i try and access the Grafana dashboard remotely/not logged into the AWS, I cannot access it. I have tried using both the public and private IP address:3000 - but neither have worked.

I dont know if I am missing something obvious, or if i need to do anything else...any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Just have exactly the same problem. Maybe Grafana requires IPV6 enabled? Actually, I got no idea what to do!.. Don't you find a workaround yet?

Comment: I ended up switching from EC2 to AWS lightsail running an Ubuntu. I opened port 3000 on IPv4 and IPv6 and it worked perfectly without any issues.